# react native notification badge count (android)

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

I'm not sure it's the right place to ask because I don't have a specific problem with my code (yet)
But I don't understand something basic about the notification badge count, regarding push notifications (on Android):

I saw this library for example:

```
react-native-shortcutbadger
```

and in order to change the badge count we can use:

```
ShortcutBadger.applyCount(count);
```

But this should be done on the receiver side? Or when the notification is being sent?
What I don't get is that the receiver can have their app shut down, so how will the badge count take place?

On iOS for example you can assign the badge count while sending the notification payload.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my understanding you have whenever a notification is received you have the listeners available for the notifications. You need to get the unread notifications count and set the badge, but remember this feature is not available for all the mobile manufacturers and android levels

Comment: Thanks, so it means that the app (of the receiver user) must be open in order to change the badge count? But if it's already open and the notification can be read, why would we need to update the count?

Comment: The default behavior of android will show the count in the notification shade, this is how it work for one signal with react native. The library seems to be pretty old so cant recommend this

Comment: Yes you're right this is the default behavior, so today the badge count is not being used anymore?